# greasemonkey userscript injects variables within another variable

Tags: javascript, variables, split, greasemonkey, quotes

So currently I am trying to add a feature to a userscript I have made.

Currently the userscript will get some text into a variable.  Now there are also have 2 vars, that currently are for adding text to the begenning and end of the text in the first var. Here is a code sample to make you better understand what it is currently doing

```
elmTextarea.value   = opening + elmTextarea.value + closing;
```

Where elmTextarea is the string that the userscript got and opening and closing are the things I put in the beginning and end of it.

Now, what I want to happen is that if the variable elmTextarea includes any [quote*]blahblahblah[/quote] it essentially will exclude those areas(not the star could be anything, it is in the format

```
[quote='name' pid='20784507' dateline='1331755619'])
```

but could also be just [quote]

So here is a quick example so you can better understand

if elmTextarea is

```
blahbla
[quote='name' pid='20784507' dateline='1331755619']
some more text
[/quote]

here is some more

[quote='name' pid='20523454507' dateline='1335435619']
some more text in here
[/quote]

and finally this text
```

it would become

```
opening + blahbla + closing
[quote='name' pid='20784507' dateline='1331755619']
some more text
[/quote]

opening + here is some more + closing

[quote='name' pid='20523454507' dateline='1335435619']
some more text in here
[/quote]

opening + and finally this text + closing
```

So I have an idea as to how this would work, and here is my attempted implementation

```
var openingquote = closing + "[quote";
var closingquote = "[/quote]" + opening;
elmTextarea.value   = opening + elmTextarea.value + closing;
elmTextarea.value = elmTextarea.value.replace(/[quote/gim, openingquote);
elmTextarea.value = elmTextarea.value.replace(/[\/quote]/gim, closingquote);
```

but adding these lines into my code makes my whole script not work.  Any ideas as to why this does not work and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets have a special meaning in a Regular expression. These should also be escaped:

```
elmTextarea.value = elmTextarea.value.replace(/\[quote/gim, openingquote);
elmTextarea.value = elmTextarea.value.replace(/\[\/quote]/gim, closingquote);
//                                             ^ Escape [ using \[
```